# Renew login session if user remain active in Android TV/Fire TV

Tags: android, android-tv, amazon-fire-tv

Once user login to my Fire TV/Android TV app, they have a 4-hour login session. Neither the Fire TV nor the Android TV remote has an exit button. Users usually press the "home" button to minimize the app to access other applications they installed. In such a scenario, suppose a user access the app and then minimizes the app after using it for a couple of hours. And when the user re-opens the app again after another hour, they will see the screen where they left off before. In such a case, how can I extend their login session while the user remains active within the app without having them log in again?

Currently, my API server generates a token when user login to the app, and there is another API running every 30 seconds to check if that token was expired.

Answer (score 1):

The `onResume` method of your Activity will be triggered whenever the Activity is brought to the foreground and ready for user input, so you can check the token there, but it sounds like this is less an Android problem and more an architecture issue.

> there is another API running every 30 seconds to check if that token was expired.

I *highly* recommend not doing this. The standard way of handling this is that when the user signs in, they get a long-lived token tied to that specific device. That token is used to fetch a short-lived token (such as your current 4-hour one). Other than the token refresh, all API requests should be made with the short-lived token.

The server should validate every short lived token that comes in and return a 4xx error if the token is expired. The app should listen to the 4xx errors and automatically fetch a new short-lived token (via the long-lived token) when it's expired. To make things smarter, you can also add code to check prior to that (e.g., attempt to get a new token after 3 hours and retry with exponential backoff).

This means you don't waste hundreds of background checks on the token when they're not necessary, any compromise of the short-lived token means the device/user is only at risk for a few hours, and you can provide the ability for the user to remotely log a device out (revoke the long-lived and short-lived token).

There are a lot of variations of this pattern, but the most known one is probably OAuth 2.0, so you could read up on that to better understand the idea. For that one, the short-lived token is the "access token" (it lets you access the API content) and the long-lived token is the "refresh token" (it lets you refresh the access token).